# Memory Aliasing to a specific Flash Sector

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, microcontroller, boot

I have an STM32 Mcu in which I flashed a BootLoader at the start of the Flash (0x0800_0000) and an Application at the 0x0801_0000 address (Sector 4).

If I am debugging my Application code and I reset the chip, the code switches to the Bootloader. I understand from this that the 0x0800_0000 address is aliased to the 0x0000_0000 of the Cpu and the mcu will always execute the code from the Bootloader first after reset.

My question is, is it possible for me to alias the 0x0000_0000 address to the Application start address (or generally speaking to a specific address in the Flash memory other than 0x0800_0000) so that it starts from there directly after reset ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the STM32 model. In some STM32F7, H7 and other models you have special option bytes which specify the boot address

Most STM32 MCUs does not have it and the processor starts from the beginning of FLASH (or RAM / system ROM - but it is not interesting for us now). The bootloader should check presence of the firmware and its integrity and then pass the control to the firmware by

- setting the stack pointer
- setting the vector table
- disabling interrupts
- putting all used by bootloader peripherals to the reset state

and eventually calling the firmware reset handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am actually using an STM32F429ZI, it looks likes it doesn't have this possibility among the option bytes. 
Could you refer to a STM32F7 having this possibility ? 
What you explained is what I am doing for the moment (Conditions check and then Jumping to Application)

Comment: @E_genin STM32F746NG for example

Comment: Hmmm, I couldn't see in the documentation how the Mcu can start from a specific sector of the flash (0800_1000 for example). For the flash it's either 0x0800_0000 or 0x0020_0000 (ITCM Vs AXIM) which kind of falls on the same thing as the rest of Mcus, isn't it ? Or I understood something wrong ?

Comment: @E_genin yes, you do understand it wrong. You need to read the documentation (Reference Manual).  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLGxF.png

Comment: Wow, it took me a while to figure it out (I hope ...). So if I want to boot from let's say Sector 3 (0x0800_8000), I should set in BOOT_ADD0 a value of 0x2002, right ?

Comment: @E_genin you need to read more (not only the page I posted. First read how the memory is organized https://i.stack.imgur.com/JijG1.png https://www.st.com/resource/en/product_training/STM32F7_System_SYSCFG.pdf

Comment: I actually did, I just needed a confirmation. Anyway I get now the big picture, thanks a lot @gulpr for the prompt answers !